# Reset DataGridView formatting to default

Tags: c#, datagridview

I color invalid data red in a DataGridView.  After the user makes changes, I would like to just reset all formatting back to default so I can look for errors and mark them red again without having to worry about which cells have been fixed and need to be set back to normal.

Is there a quick/easy way to do this without resetting the datasource?

Thanks!

Edit:  Guess I didn't communicate clearly enough.  It's an import app that moves data from a csv file into a sql table.  I put the csv data into the dgv and verify that it's not going to cause any errors before importing (i.e. wrong data type or data is too long) and mark those cells red if so.

They hit a 'verify data' button to run this process before importing and when they hit it again I just want to clear the formatting and start over.

Comment: Have you used AutoFormat (Side bar menu) to format the GridView? If yes then select the Remove Formatting .

Comment: No, all formatting is automated in code.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: How are you setting it as invalid which event, code please

Comment: @BrandonMoore my question was how are you doing it ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta dgv.[colName, row].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

Comment: Because of the way Styles are inherited, you can safely set the DefaultCellStyle of the DataGridViewRow to null. It will return a new style object the next time a property is called on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
var ds = dgv.DataSource;
dgv.DataSource = null;
dgv.DataSource = ds;
```

That caused all the formatting to go back to default values like I wanted without having to reload my data.  If there's some property or other better way to do this that I'm overlooking though then put it on here so I can mark it as a better answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately. I'll post the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, basically in the same way I edited the colors.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dgv.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your Windows is configured to use a different application-workspace color, such as in High-Contrast mode.

Comment: In that case, use `Color.Empty`

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old post, but for those who come across this need in the future, the following also works if your `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` is bound to a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgv_Main.DataSource;
dt.AcceptChanges();
```